# WPF DataGrid change auto-generated column

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a MVVM project with a DataGrid, that uses DataTable with a dynamic number of columns.
That means DataGrid has to auto generate its columns.
I want to change one generated DataGridTextColumn ("Col B" in code, for typeof(PKValue)) to a DataGridComboBoxColumn.
But I can't get it to display column's data.

DataTable is created like this:

```
while (i < this.ColumnsCount1)
{
    dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col A", typeof(bool)));
    i++;

    dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col B", typeof(PKValue)));
    i++;

    dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col C", typeof(string)));
    i++;
}
```

IDItem class:

```
public class PKValue : ICloneable
{
    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
    public int PK { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

With this code - DataGrid creates "Col B" as DataGridTextColumn.
Then I use this code, trying to change auto-generated text column to a combobox column:

```
protected override void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyType == typeof(PKValue))
    {
        MainViewModel mainViewModel = null;
        UserControl userControl = FindParent<UserControl>(this) as UserControl;
        Window window = FindParent<Window>(this) as Window;

        if (userControl != null && userControl.DataContext.GetType().Equals(typeof(MainViewModel)))
        {
            mainViewModel = userControl.DataContext as MainViewModel;
        }
        else if (window != null && window.DataContext.GetType().Equals(typeof(MainViewModel)))
        {
            mainViewModel = window.DataContext as MainViewModel;
        }

        if (mainViewModel != null)
        {
            DataGridComboBoxColumn dataGridComboBoxColumn = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();

            Binding bindingItemsSource = new Binding();
            bindingItemsSource.Source = mainViewModel.PKValueItemsSource;
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(dataGridComboBoxColumn, ItemsSourceProperty, bindingItemsSource);

            Binding bindingSelectedItem = new Binding(e.PropertyName);
            bindingSelectedItem.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(dataGridComboBoxColumn, SelectedItemProperty, bindingSelectedItem);

            dataGridComboBoxColumn.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
            dataGridComboBoxColumn.SelectedValuePath = "PK";

            e.Column = dataGridComboBoxColumn;
        }

        base.OnAutoGeneratingColumn(e);
    }
}
```

DataGrid does change "Col B" to DataGridComboBoxColumn without any warnings, shows ItemsSource properly, but it doesn't display existing value of the field.
When I select an item from a dropdown - it gives a warning *"Cannot create default converter to perform 'two-way' conversions between types 'WPFGridMatrix.Models.PKValue' and 'System.String'"*. And when I create a converter that returns a simple string "abc" - still, nothing is displayed in the column. My guess is that using simply "e.Column = dataGridComboBoxColumn;" is not enough, but how to do that properly?

Comment: Why using auto-generated columns? It seems that for you manually adding them would be a better fit and you will have the control you need.

Comment: You probably right ... I'll try that.

Comment: Yes, that worked, thanks